# cannot login to mysql root from vagrant, but can from sudo

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I just reinstall mysql, which is now running 5.7.9. I'm using vagrant.

I try to login to mysql with `mysql -u root -proot` and I get: `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

I then ran `sudo -i`, and `mysql -u root -proot`, and it allowed me to login with full root access.

Any idea why this is and how do I fix it? is the root user secured in some way on newer versions of mysql that make it inaccessible unless you're a sudo/root user in ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Try these things: 
Try login by using `vagrant` as username instead of root, if that satisfies your problem.

Other things you can try is: Changing the password for root. Check the users using:

```
sudo mysql 
SELECT * FROM mysql.user
```

Check if you have user named `root` then try:

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`

You may get some warnings, use `SHOW WARNINGS` to see them.
Below link may help:
https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/16/change-user-password-in-mysql-5-7-with-plugin-auth_socket/